# Junit Test Class Failure

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I have written Junit test for the following method:

```
@Service
public class EnterpriseCustomerVerificationService {

 @Autowired
 CreditCheckRepository creditCheckRepository;

 public String FTACheck(StandardInputHeader charterHeaderInputInfo,
            Holder<StandardOutputHeader> charterHeaderOutputInfo, Long sys, Long prin, Long agent)
            throws EnterpriseCustomerVerificationException {

        String prepay = null;
        List<String> prepays = null;

        charterHeaderOutputInfo.value = new StandardOutputHeader(charterHeaderInputInfo);
        prepays = creditCheckRepository.getCSGPrepay(sys.toString(), prin.toString(), agent.toString(),
                charterHeaderInputInfo.getAuditUser());

        if (prepays != null && prepays.size() > 0) {
            prepay = prepays.get(0);
        }

        return prepay;
    }
}
```

**CreditCheckRepository class**

```
@Component
public class CreditCheckRepository {

    @Autowired
    SPGetCSGPrepay spGetCSGPrepay;

    public List<String> getCSGPrepay(String sys, String prin, String agent, String auditUser) {
        return spGetCSGPrepay.execute(sys, prin, agent, auditUser);
    }
}
```

Test Method

```
package com.charter.enterprise.credit.service;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import javax.xml.ws.Holder;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EnterpriseCustomerVerificationServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    EnterpriseCustomerVerificationService 
    enterpriseCustormerVerificationServiceMock;


    @Mock
    CreditCheckRepository creditCheckRepository;

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();
    StandardInputHeader charterHeaderInputInfo;
    Holder<StandardOutputHeader> charterHeaderOutputInfo;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        charterHeaderInputInfo = new StandardInputHeader();
        charterHeaderInputInfo.setAuditUser("test");
        charterHeaderInputInfo.setClientIp("127.0.0.1");
        charterHeaderOutputInfo = new Holder<StandardOutputHeader>();


        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(
                enterpriseCustormerVerificationServiceMock,
                "creditCheckRepository", creditCheckRepository);

    }
    @Test
        public void getFTACheckTest() {

            String auditUser = "User";
            Long sys = 123L;
            Long prin = 456L;
            Long agent = 789L;

            List<String> prepays = new ArrayList<String>();
            prepays.add("ABCDEF");

            Mockito.when(
                    creditCheckRepository.getCSGPrepay("123", "456", "789", "User"))
                    .thenReturn(prepays);
            // Mockito.when(spGetCSGPrepay.execute("123", "456","789",
            // "User")).thenReturn(prepays);
            String prepay = enterpriseCustormerVerificationServiceMock.FTACheck(
                    charterHeaderInputInfo, charterHeaderOutputInfo, sys, prin,
                    agent);
            assertNotNull(prepay);
    }
}
```

My question is I always get null whenever I try to do assertion check on: **prepay Object**.
also I injectMocked as EnterpriseCustomerVerificationService enterpriseCustormerVerificationServiceMock;
Please suggest me is there is something wrong with my business logic or what?

Comment: have you debugged it, and checked that you mocked for the right values?

Comment: yes I already debugged it . but the object prepay is not getting any value every time it is showing null.

Comment: Mockito.when(
                creditCheckRepository.getCSGPrepay("123", "456", "789", "User"))
                .thenReturn(prepays); why are you hardcoded the values, use matchers instead like anyString, any()

Comment: call is going in FTACheck method ?? Can you debug and check response of creditCheckRepository.getCSGPrepay() ?

Comment: @TmP since creditCheckRepository is mocked creditCheckRepository.getCSGPrepay() always returning null.

Comment: where is `enterpriseCustormerVerificationServiceMock`defined? As it is right now this won't even compile!

Comment: @inovaovao Sorry I forgot to put it in my code now you can check

Comment: Looks like you are trying to inject creditCheckRepository twice: first with @InjectMocks and then againg with ReflectionTestUtils.setField()

Comment: @PraveenKumarMekala Thanks and Yes it is working now by using matchers like anyString() or any() instead of passing hardcoded values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did some oops with your arguments:

```
creditCheckRepository.getCSGPrepay("123", "456", "789", "User"))
```

should be

```
creditCheckRepository.getCSGPrepay("123", "456", "789", "test"))
```

As a side note, you should use [`ArgumentMatchers`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.9.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html) (might be `Matchers` if you use an old version) to avoid such issue:

```
Mockito.when(creditCheckRepository.getCSGPrepay(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
   ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn(prepays);
```

Comment: Why `anyString()` - in 2017 that would be just `any()`?!

Comment: @RC Thanks its working now if I use Matchers like this : Mockito.when(
    creditCheckRepository.getCSGPrepay(Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyString()))
    .thenReturn(prepays);